# How to get app on foreground in Android app?

Tags: android, foreground

I'm trying to get the app running on the foreground in Android. I have read several questions but lots of them are either too old or require certain permissions such as `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` which I'd like to avoid.

I was trying the following:

```
public String foregroundApp()
{
    String foreground="Black mirror";
    Context newContext = getApplicationContext();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) newContext.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses){
        if(appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
            foreground=appProcess.processName;
            Log.i("Foreground App", appProcess.processName);
        }
    }
    return foreground;
}
```

This code only works if the foreground app is the one that implements the activity that calls `foregroundApp`. Is there any workaround you can suggest? I want to get the app on the foreground without requiring permission.

Comment: What you mean by running app in foreground?

Comment: the app that the user is looking at if he's using the phone. If the phone is in sleep mode, I'm ok with returning null.

Comment: you can't get running apps starting from something like Android 6